# cypher query to return or keep only the final sequence when variable length relationship identifiers are used

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to keep or return only the final full sequences of nodes instead of all subpaths when variable length identifiers are used in order to do further operations on each of the final full sequence path.

MATCH path = (S:Person)-[rels:NEXT*]->(E:Person)................

eg: find all sequences of nodes with their names in the given list , say ['graph','server','db'] with same 'seqid' property exists in the relationship in between.

i.e.

(graph)->(server)-(db) with same seqid :1

(graph)->(db)->(server) with same seqid :1     //there can be another matching
                                                        sequence with same seqid

(graph)->(db)->(server) with same seqid :2

Is there a way to keep only the final sequence of nodes say ' (graph)->(server)->(db)' for each sequences instead of each of the subpath of a large sequence like (graph)->(server) or (server)->(db)

pls help me to solve this.........

(I am using neo4j 2.3.6 community edition via java api in embedded mode..)

Comment: Can you share the Cypher queries that are matching on all sequences?

Comment: Also, do you have any requirements on what to do if the same endpoint node can be reached via multiple valid paths? Also I'm not seeing S being treated as some unique start node, it's matching on all :Person nodes. Is this kind of query meant to be applied to all :Persons, or from a single (or group) of start nodes?

Comment: Is it fair to assume that you want your starting node to not have an incoming :NEXT relationship? And if not, what kind of criteria should be used to determine the starting node of a sequence?

Comment: No need to give a starting node. Retrieve all sequences of nodes with their names in the given list and have same 'seqid' in the relationship property in between. MATCH p=(a)-[rels:NEXT*]->(b) WHERE ALL(n in nodes(p) WHERE n.name in ['graph', 'server' ,'db']) and  ALL( r in rels WHERE rels[0]['seqid'] = r.seqid )return p  --------------> this query will return all  sequences with same 'seqid '. But I only want to have the final sequence of nodes for each of the sequences with same 'seqid' instead of  each of the sub paths .

Comment: The only way I know to do this currently is by defining the characteristics of your start and end nodes (so they can't traverse before the start node or beyond the end node without breaking predicates) then finding the paths between them. Or, to avoid cartesian product, define start nodes first, then match with variable length relationships with predicates, adding an additional predicate on your end node of the pattern so it can only match on the end node of the sequence and not earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we could really use here is a longestSequences() function that would do exactly what you want it to do, expand the pattern such that a and b would always be matched to start and end points in the sequence such that the pattern is not a subset of any other matched pattern.

I created a feature request on neo4j for exactly this: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/7760

And until that gets implemented, we'll have to make do with some alternate approach. I think what we'll have to do is add additional matching to restrict a and b to start and end nodes of full sequences.

Here's my proposed query:

```
WITH ['graph', 'server' ,'db'] as names
MATCH p=(a)-[rels:NEXT*]->(b) 
WHERE ALL(n in nodes(p) WHERE n.name in names) 
AND ALL( r in rels WHERE rels[0]['seqid'] = r.seqid ) 
WITH names, p, a, rels, b
// check if b is a subsequence node instead of an end node
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)-[rel:NEXT]->(c)
WHERE c.name in names
AND rel.seqid = rels[0]['seqid']
// remove any existing matches where b is a subsequence node
WITH names, p, a, rels, b, c
WHERE c IS NULL
WITH names, p, a, rels, b
// check if a is a subsequence node instead of a start node
OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[rel:NEXT]->(a)
WHERE d.name in names
AND rel.seqid = rels[0]['seqid']
// remove any existing matches where a is a subsequence node
WITH p, a, b, d
WHERE d IS NULL
RETURN p, a as startNode, b as endNode
```

Comment: Thank you very much for ur help....But pls help...it will not capture those sequences that appears in different order with same seqid..i.e. if(graph)->(server)->(db) with seqid 2 and  (db)->(graph)->(server) with same seqid 2 is there, then it will not display both..If possible pls help me.

Comment: In your comment, are those two sequences (graph->server->db, db->graph->server) separate, or are you talking about an overlap (where the actual sequence is db->graph->server->db and you need to match on the two distinct sequences within? Also, can you clarify if the sequences you want to find should contain nodes with names in the given list of names (so server->server->server would be fine), or if you are looking for sequences with exactly one of each name in the given list of names, no repeats?

Comment: Actually i want to store different documents in a graph based representation with each unique words will be stored once  and a unique seqid for each document will be given as a relationship property to identify the sequence of nodes representing each document. ur query correctly give results when the list of nodes in the list appears in different order in different documents. But there are chances where this sequences can appear in different order in the same document itself at different places.. All relationships are of type 'NEXT'.

Comment: If possible,pls help me.

Comment: again the parent node or previous node of these path sequences are different  but with same seqid.e.g nosql->(graph->server->db) and relational->(db->graph->server)

Comment: @SoumyaGeorge Is this still an issue, and is order really a problem? There's nothing in my query that enforces any kind of ordering on the nodes or names in the path. If this is still a problem, please update your description, preferably with an actual graph or graph data demonstrating the problem so we can work with it.

Comment: I found another solution for it by deleting that words before adding into the graph and dealing with it by adding appropriate edges. I know it cannot be solved..no probs...Thank you very much for your kindness...

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

This query might do what you want:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[rel:NEXT]->(:Person)
WHERE NOT (:Person)-[:NEXT {seqid: rel.seqid}]->(p1)
WITH DISTINCT p1, rel.seqid AS seqid
MATCH path = (p1)-[:NEXT* {seqid: seqid}]->(p2:Person)
WHERE NOT (p2)-[:NEXT {seqid: seqid}]->(:Person)
RETURN path;
```

It first identifies all `Person` nodes (`p1`) with at least one outgoing `NEXT` relationship that have no incoming `NEXT` relationships (with the same `seqid`), and their distinct outgoing `seqid` values. Then it finds all "complete" paths (i.e., paths whose start and end nodes have no incoming or outgoing `NEXT` relationships with the desired `seqid`, respectively) starting at each `p1` node and having relationships all sharing the same `seqid`. Finally, it returns each complete path.

If you just want to get the `name` property of all the `Person` nodes in each path, try this query (with a different `RETURN` clause):

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[rel:NEXT]->(:Person)
WHERE NOT (:Person)-[:NEXT {seqid: rel.seqid}]->(p1)
WITH DISTINCT p1, rel.seqid AS seqid
MATCH path = (p1)-[:NEXT* {seqid: seqid}]->(p2:Person)
WHERE NOT (p2)-[:NEXT {seqid: seqid}]->(:Person)
RETURN EXTRACT(n IN NODES(path) | n.name);
```

Comment: That will probably work, provided that the start and end nodes are defined by not having :NEXT relationships to/from according to what's here, and if that's the case this is definitely the start of the best solution (still need the name restrictions in there). But if there can be :NEXT relationships to and from the start and end nodes but with different seqids, or even with the same seqid but from/to nodes with names we don't care about, we'll need a more powerful query.

Comment: I have edited my answer to take into account what I believe are the valid critiques from @InverseFalcon.

Comment: pls help... i only want the sequence of selected list of elements...['graph','server','db'] that can occur in any order with same seqid or different

Comment: Are you tying to get the `name` property of all the nodes in each path? If so, I have modified my answer to show how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (S:Person)-[r:NEXT]->(:Person) 
    // Possible starting node
    WHERE NOT ( (:Person)-[:NEXT {seqid: r.seqid}]->(S) )
WITH S, 
     // Collect all possible values of `seqid`
     collect (distinct r.seqid) as seqids
UNWIND seqids as seqid
// Possible terminal node
MATCH (:Person)-[r:NEXT {seqid: seqid}]->(E:Person) 
    WHERE NOT ( (E)-[:NEXT {seqid: seqid}]->(:Person) )
WITH S, 
     seqid, 
     collect(distinct E) as ES
UNWIND ES as E
    MATCH path = (S)-[rels:NEXT* {seqid: seqid}]->(E) 
RETURN S, 
       seqid, 
       path
```

Comment: pls help... i only want the sequence of selected list of elements...['graph','server','db'] that can occur in any order with same seqid or different